# Vue CLI 3 remove console.log and code comments with Terser

Tags: vue.js, webpack, build, vue-cli-3, terser

I'm using VUE CLI 3 and I need to remove the *console.log* and *code comments* from the production built. This is my [Terser](https://github.com/terser/terser) setup:

**webpack.config.js** in **src** folder

```
    module.exports = {
mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          ecma: undefined,
          warnings: false,
          parse: {},
          compress: {drop_debugger},
          mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
          module: false,
          output: null,
          toplevel: false,
          nameCache: null,
          ie8: false,
          keep_classnames: undefined,
          keep_fnames: false,
          safari10: false,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

My production workflow: Run `npm run build` -> `cd dist` -> `npm run serve`

The production build still outputs all *console.log* statements and shows code comments `(<!-- -->)`.
What do I need to change to remove them?

Comment: Try : terserOptions: {
            ecma: 6,
            compress: {
              drop_console: true
            },
            output: {
              comments: false,
              beautify: false
            }
          }

Comment: @JeffProd Just tried it but I received the same result. console.log and comments are still visible in the output. Any ideas?

Comment: npm run serve runs the dev build, does it not? Terser is only applied to the production build.

Comment: @madflow That would explain a lot. I'm running _npm run build_ -> _npm run serve_ on the _dist_ build. What is the correct command to test the _dist_ build before distribution? (_npm run build_ is setting the _production mode_ right?)

Comment: Answer is below :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all: make sure you are configuring [Terser](https://github.com/terser/terser#minify-options) correctly:

```
terserOptions: {
    ecma: 6,
    compress: { drop_console: true },
    output: { comments: false, beautify: false }
}
```

`npm run serve`

is usually a shortcut for:

`vue-cli-service`

```
vue-cli-service --help

  Usage: vue-cli-service <command> [options]

  Commands:

    serve     start development server
    build     build for production
    inspect   inspect internal webpack config
    lint      lint and fix source files
```

So when your workflow is the above mentioned `npm run build -> cd dist -> npm run serve` then you are actually starting the dev server, which does not apply Terser.

In order to run the production build you can use any [webserver](https://github.com/imgarylai/awesome-webservers) capable of serving static content:

NodeJs examples:

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s dist
```

or

```
npm install -g node-static
static dist
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. I'm running the build with _serve -s dist_ now but the logs and comments are still in the build - same goes for the uploaded build on my server. I opened a new question to find the root of this issue. LINK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328991/vue-cli-3-vue-config-js-vs-webpack-config-js-for-plugins

Comment: I updated my answer - it works for me when I add `ecma: 6` like mentioned above in the comments. Would be interesting to know...why... @Tom